# Is there any method to update Col B when Col A contains Only Numeric, Col A

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two Col's Namely A & B, Need to Update B col when A col contains only Numeric

I have to Update The col only If the A contains Numeric Else exit

I am stuck with it, below is my Query

```
Update set empID = New_EMP_id 
Where RegID = New_RegID AND (RegSeq = '%[^0-9]%' or RegSeq='' or RegSeq = 'NULL')
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: I'm confused. You say to update only if `A contains numeric`, but yet you have `= '' or NULL`.

Comment: @AjaySimha try using `isnumeric(...)`

Comment: No, I just noticed that `CONTAINS` a numeric.. meaning it can be numbers and letters, but must contain a numeric within the string.

Comment: Hi this is MS sql  server 2012,

Comment: I want to Update Only if it Contains only Numeric or if its null. if it contains NON NUMERIC it should not update

Answer (score 1):

Based on your syntax, I am going to assume that you are using SQL Server.  If so:

```
update t
    set empID = @New_EMP_id 
where RegID = @New_RegID and
      (RegSeq not like '%[^0-9]%' or RegSeq is null);
```

Comment: HI, I tried the example, but if the RegSeq has Non Numeric its getting updated, for Example RegSeq haS 366?67 empID get updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TRY_CAST, something like

```
UPDATE table1 
SET empID = New_EMP_id 
WHERE RegID = New_RegID AND (ReqSeq IS NULL OR TRY_CAST(ReqSeq AS INT) IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this assuming `sql-server` version greather or equal than `2008`,

```
Update set empID = New_EMP_id 
Where RegID = New_RegID and (isnumeric(RegSeq) = 1 or RegSeq='' or RegSeq = 'NULL')
```

Comment: Hi Its SQL Server 2012, RegSeg Col in nvarchar(7), Some of entries start with 0 Zero also, for Example : 004931,

Comment: Thanks a ton, Able to execute Query on my system successfully,

Comment: @AjaySimha I am glad to hear that. Have a nice day :).

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` [is problematic](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/time-stop-using-isnumeric/), and is not necessary in this case, since the OP has SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Declare @t table ( a varchar (10),b varchar(10))

Insert into @t values ('TEST','TEST')
Insert into @t values ('ABC','1245A')
Insert into @t values ('ABC','1245')



Update a1 set a='Updated' 
from @t a1
where ISNUMERIC(b) = 1

select * from @t
```